# Can you use $_FILES[tmp_name] for remembering file location?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am building a form right now that returns the user back to the form itself if there is missing fields or fields are entered wrong. One of the inputs is a image file. I was wondering if you want to echo out the image location again, do you use `$_FILES[tmp_name]`?

e.g. `value="$_FILES[tmp_name]"` to echo back the location so the user doesn't have to reselect the image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible this way. 
the `$_FILES[tmp_name]` reflects the full path of the already uploaded image on the server.
an its not possible to pre-select the upload field in the browser and its also not possible to get the full client-side path of the uploaded file.

so in case of an error, you could copy this temporary file to another location and display the already uploaded image to the user instead of giving him the upload field again.
but you need to make sure to delete this copied image if the user didn't try to fix his invalid fields.

or you seperate the validation of the fields from the image upload part. using some ajax magic or seperate form.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `$_FILES['tmp_name']` in this way, as that isn't the name it had on the users computer, but the temporary name that it has on your server in your `tmp` folder. Not sure if there is a way to do this. I'll look into it and let you know if I find anything, but I doubt there is.

If you used an AJAX file upload, you wouldn't have to worry about this though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you could try to use a value attribute on a file input to see that it has no effect.

Imagine that if you could do this it would be a serious security problem (ie: hide a file input with a pre-filled value with a common path for an important file and get it the same time with some other details)

Answer (score 0):

If the form is submitted via normal html form submission then you do not have access to the user's file path. Your best bet is to use an AJAX form submission.